# Putting resources into my eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

I've just changed to eclipse an I'm used to manually managing my project structure with Windows filesystem (compiling my .java files into bin with a batch-script). Whenever I wanted my classes to use a .png-file, I simply put this file into the .bin folder.

If I put my .png-files in the bin-folder of the eclipse project as I'm used to, the classes will be able to load the pictures just fine. But sometimes, I don't know when, Eclipse simply deletes the bin-folder and creates a new one based on the contents of the src folder (which doesn't have my .png files). Putting the files into the src-folder (again, manually from the windows file-system) doesn't actually put them in my Eclipse project.

So what I want to ask is: Why/when does Eclipse completely rebuild the bin-folder. And how can I put resources, like .png-files, into my Eclipse project?

Comment: Are you simply drag & dropping the resources in to your project? If so then you'd want to explicitly "Import" them by right-clicking your project and selecting import... this may prevent the deletion you are talking about from happening.

Comment: I tried that, actually. But since my current solution is to manually store my .png files in the src folder (and then copy them into bin) Eclipse won't allow me to import those files, saying: "Source is in the hierarchy of the destination". Which is obviously an easy fix, but just raises some other questions, so I didn't go for it. Like, "if it is already there, why isn't it showing in Eclipse"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course there is no point in putting files in the bin as it may be rebuilt by Eclipse whenever needed and you'll loose your changes.

by default Eclipse is set up to rebuild the project automatically, you can see that by looking in the "Project" menu entry, you can force Eclipse to rebuild your project by choosing "clean" in that "Project" menu.

So now you should have more control over when Eclipse is building your project.

Regarding adding resources files, I'm not sure what your current project directory structure is, in order to add / remove directories in the project, right click on the project root in the project Explorer side pane and choose "Properties" entry (at the bottom), then you can go to "Java Build Path" -> "Source" tab and manage the project directories.

last, if you change files on your disk and not through Eclipse, right click on the project root and choose "refresh" entry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I put some .png files in the src folder of the Eclipse structure. When I afterwards press Project --> clean, files that are in the bin folder but not in src folder aren't deleted. Files from src folder aren't put into bin either.

Comment: But the "refresh" button was just EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you very, very much :)